# How to extract/convert values from JSON response to a VB.NET Object and vice versa?

Tags: vb.net, json, serialization

I'm getting a JSON response after accessing a web service with my window application written in VB.NET. How can I convert the JSON response to a VB.NET object and vice versa? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [PW.JSON](http://www.pozzware.com/pozzware/Corsi/Programmazione/VB.NET/JSON%20Library.aspx). As far as I know, it is the only library to serialize / deserialize JSON objects in VB.net. [JSON.org](http://json.org) lists a number of different libraries for JSON serialization at the bottom of the page, but unfortunately, PW.JSON appears to be the only one for VB.net.